# Contemporary philosophers on intellectual intuition?

Tags: reference-request, idealism, german-philosophy, intuition

The 18th-19th century German philosophers (the so-called "German Idealists"), and other Post-kantian philosophers have used the term "intellectual intuition" in slightly different ways, but generally as a sort of perception, a sixth sense of sort, that allows the subject to sense abstract objects, a priori truth, and in the field of Kant - the noumenon world.*

As this concept is highly useful in Kantian philosophy, I wouldn't expect to find it anywhere outside this school. Even so, I'd like to ask if there's any contemporary philosopher that uses and/or researches the concept of intellectual intuition inside the Kantian school or outside of it?

---

*couldn't find any credible source to cite an exact definition, I'd be happy to include one if provided in the comments.

Comment: I think the term as used by German idealists and romantics is specific to them, as it was used to overcome the Kantian problem of the unknowability of the thing in itself. There are variations [in Bergson](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bergson/#3) and [Husserl's *Wesensschau*](https://www.iep.utm.edu/phenom/), but they are not really a mystical window into the thing in itself that *Anschauung* was. Heidegger's *denkende Anschauung* is closer. Of late, you may like [Zöller's take on McDowell](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/trans/v33n1/a05v33n1.pdf) in this context.

Comment: I cannot make sense of the phrase 'intellectual intuition' since it seems to be an oxymoron. Intellectual knowledge is not intuitive. albeit it ma be informed by intuition. The problem is the word ;'intuition'. You could say mysticism is the study of intuitive knowledge, but most people use 'intuition' to mean something vague and uncertain.

Comment: @PeterJ how would you describe/name differently Kant's concept then?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - I've never tried to disentangle the details Kant's views on epistemology since he does not have a viable theory. If you google 'non-intuitive immediate knowledge' the complications caused by the term 'intuitive' may become apparent. It has two or three significantly different meanings, which is why I don't like it. Perhaps for Kant 'intellectual intuition' is a meaningful idea, but for me it's highly problematic since intuitive knowledge would be non-intellectual. The problems of language.... . . .  . .